# How to extract duplicate orders from DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, having-clause

Using SQL Server 2014. Taking the following recordset:

[image]

I need to find a way to extract the ordOrderNum which is duplicates, with a different DeliveryNum. In this example, orders 93400460 and 93400467 would be extract, because they are duplicates. Order 93408170 is ok. How can I do that??!

thanks for your time and help

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select ordOrderNum 
from mytable
group by ordOrderNum
having min(ordDeliveryNum) <> max(ordDeliveryNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
ORDORDERNUM, ORDLINENUM, 
COUNT(*) FROM TABLE
GROUP BY 
ORDORDERNUM, ORDLINENUM
Having count(*)>1
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesn't work. It returns nothing

Comment: I think you meant to use ordDeliveryNum and not ordLineNum.  Making that change will return the correct results